# CLI command to check if there are shelved files in a given Perforce change-list

Tags: perforce

I have an automation that picks Perforce change-list as input and unshelves and tests the changes in it. Often people forget to shelve the files and start the automation with a change-list that doesn't contain shelved files. In this case we get false successful runs.

Is there a command I can use to check if there are shelved files in a given Perforce change-list?

Comment: Similar use-case is reported in https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-57094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most commands you can "preview" an `unshelve` operation by adding the `-n` flag.  Hence `p4 unshelve -n CHANGELIST` will let you know if there are no shelved files, but won't actually unshelve anything if there are.

An alternative method is to check the contents of the changelist with `p4 files @=CHANGE`.  The `@=CHANGE` revision specifier will only match files that are in the depot, so for a pending change it will only return results if there are shelved files.

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. Is there a way to get a Boolean (in the sense of yes/no) result without having to hardcode the text returned by the p4 commands ("Change XXXXX - no file(s) to unshelve.")?

Comment: It's pretty easy if you use one of the scripting APIs.  If you're just scripting around the CLI output, I recommend playing around with the `-e`, `-s`, `-ztag`, and `-F` flags, which can all help give you easier strings to grep for.

Comment: I've explored the options but couldn't find parameter that would actually work for me. The closest I got is the code0 which seems to represent the message code but still seems very fragile when upgrading perforce.

Comment: Message codes are actually pretty stable, because the expectation is that client apps might be built around them.  You can even explicitly pass an API version (`-zapi=NNN`) and the server will do its best to downgrade functionality if needed to preserve old messages.